# How to play Video with iframe or embedcode in webview (Android)

Tags: android, iframe, video, webview

I dont know much about the webview, normally i'd use `Mediaplayer` and `Mediacontroller` to play video from `url` but my all videos are HD and some phone can give error or blackscreen while playing HD videos. So i decided to play video with embed code. Now i can play video with embed code but videos are not fluent. My other problem is i cant allow fullscreen. I think if i use iframe, i can allow, but i dont know how to use iframe in webview.

I want to learn, is it possible to avoid freezing in `webview` and how can i use `iframe` in `webview`, if you give example i will be much appreciate. Hope i could explain myself and you can help me.Thank in advance.

**Here is my webview code :**

```
  public class EmbedActivity extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_embed);

    WebView mWebView = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.webView1);
    WebSettings webSettings = mWebView.getSettings();
    mWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    mWebView.getSettings().setPluginState(WebSettings.PluginState.ON);
    mWebView.loadUrl("http://www.example.com/wp-nuevo/player/embed.php?key=9935");

}

   }
```

**iframe**

```
<iframe width="480" height="360" src="http://www.example.com/wp-nuevo/player/embed.php?key=11042" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

Answer (score 0):

Hello may be i am late but I hope my answer help others
you can user responsive html as

```
<div style="position: relative;overflow: hidden;width: 100%;padding-top: 45.25%;">

<iframe style="position: absolute; top: 0;  left: 0; bottom: 0; right: 0; width: 100%; height: 100%;"
title="vimeo-player" 
src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/tgbNymZ7vqY"
frameborder="0" 
>
</iframe>
```

this will match width for screen width
how to user u need to convert this html to string like

```
const val iFrame = "<div style=\"position: relative;overflow: hidden;width: 100%;padding-top: 54%;\"> <iframe width=\"360\" height=\"338\" style=\"position: absolute; top: 0;  left: 0; bottom: 0; right: 0; width: 100%; height: 100%;\" title=\"vimeo-player\" src=\"https://www.youtube.com/embed/tgbNymZ7vqY" frameborder=\"0\" allowfullscreen> </iframe> </div>"
```

then load Data to WebView like

```
        binding.webview.loadData(iFrame, "text/html", "utf-8");
```